# Auto scale page so it fits the screen

Tags: css, resize, scale

I have a site where I think
Most of my users are using desktop or laptop while they are on my site. The problem is that on some screens its only 1/4 of the screen begin used and rest is just background.
How can I make it auto scale, so it fits the screen's size??

Comment: You want to know  css media query ?

Comment: As said my page shall not be mobile responsive, but just auto scale so its use all the screen even on an 27" screen

Comment: Did I explained this wrong? I said on big screens the page only cover 1/4 and rest is background

Comment: set  width:100%  , please show ur code jsfiddle.net

Comment: Shall I use % for every thing instead of px or just for the body?

Comment: No need to 100% for body  , set on other tag  , show ur code on jsfiddle,net

Comment: My own coded stylesheet http://jsfiddle.net/W8u6L/ Edit: I use eric meyer reset too

Comment: .container-all , .header , .navigationbar , .footer{
    width:100%:
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **css3 transform**:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+  */
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);   /* IE 9 */
-o-transform: scale(0.5);    /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
transform: scale(0.5);
```

Calculate the scale ratio and apply the rules with this ratio in your script.

Do not forget to set left and top property of the transformized element as the offset ratio of the full width and height:

```
offsetRatio = (ratio - 1) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use CSS "*responsive designs*". You can find some examples here:

http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-basic-responsive-site-css-1132756

Basically, you use **min-width** / **max-width**, and **@media** to decide what to show, and how.

If you are not comfortable doing that kinda stuff, then **Bootstrap** is a good way to accomplish this, with the minimum of effort:

http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

.wrapper {
     max-width:1000px;
     margin:0 auto;
}

wrapper - is the main container of your site